# next, previous to any given object in sorted by multiple columns ActiveRecord set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I got two related models

```
class Post
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

I need to get posts ordered by 'subjects'.'name' ASC, 'posts'.'updated_at' DESC 
Then for any given **id** to get posts next and previous to Post.find(id) according to given sort order.

I order posts such way:

```
Post.joins(:subject).order('subjects.name ASC, posts.updated_at DESC')
```

But how to get next and previous posts ?

Comment: what do you want to do with next and previous?

Comment: I want to provide links to next and previous posts on Post :show view

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each_with_index` method. The method works like this:

```
a=[1,2,3]
a.each_with_index {|item, index|
  puts index.to_s+"=>"+item.to_s
}
```

produces:

`0=>1
1=>2
2=>3`

Now You can store your sorted array in a variable like:

```
@posts=Post.joins(:subject).order('subjects.name ASC, posts.updated_at DESC')
```

And, if you want the next and previous of an `id`, you can do:

```
@next=nil
@previous=nil
@posts.each_with_index {|post, index|
      if post.id==id
        @next=@posts[index+1]
        @previous=@posts[index-1]
        break
      end
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you. Is there a way to build a query to make DB do that work?